# how to pass a value for a Callable function in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, callable-statement

i'm trying to pass a value to a callback function in my code, 
i'm passing my `callback`to another function and i want it to return the `callback` a state,

here is my function I'm sending out >

```
wifiWrapper myWifiWrapper = new wifiWrapper(); //- INIZILIZING WIFI
                    myWifiWrapper.checkWifiState(this, wifiStateCallback);
```

here is my end function in the wifiWrapper class >

```
//checks if the wifi is On or Off
    public void checkWifiState (Context context, Callable callback) {


        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        boolean isOn;


        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){

            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Your Wi-Fi is enabled", //wifi is enabled
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isOn = true;

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Your Wi-Fi is disabled", //wifi is disabled
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isOn = false;

        }



        try { //trys to call back to the callable function
            callback.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and here is my Callable that i'm passing >

```
//callback for the ifiState
    Callable wifiStateCallback = new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {


            return null;
        }
    };
```

PROBLEM IS
 **I want to pass the `isOnState` to the `callable`, and can't seem to make it work.**
i'm adding

```
callback.call(isOn);
```

but it doesn't work it says  it cannot be applied

Comment: You never explained the problem you are facing with this code.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what actually your problem is?

Comment: If you are saying you callable doesnt contain boolean then pass `isOn` to `callback.call(isOn)` to your callback

Comment: hey guys sorry i thought when i added, "i want to pass the isOn State to the callable, and can't seem to make it work."  it was what i wanted to do .. i want to pass isOn to the callable function, do like this > callback.call(isOn); but this doesn't work it says that call in callble cannot be applied, @vijay_t

Comment: i Edited my first initial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add argument to `call()` out of nowhere and expect it to work. Callable's `call()` is argumentless. What you can do however, is to extend Callable and pass whatever you want via constructor:

```
class MyCallable extends Callable {

    boolean isOn;

    public MyCallable(boolean isOn) {
       mIsOn = isOn;
    }

    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        if (mIsOn) {
           ...
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

so then

```
Callable wifiStateCallback = new MyCallable(false);
```

Comment: i'm trying to add that class in my scanning barcode activity class, but it errors out the word 'Callable' it says no interface expected here. @Marcin Orlowski

Comment: can you show me on how to implemented it in my own code ? i don't understand on how to use it @Marcin Orlowski